# Single Storyboard vs Multiple Stoaryboard in XCode, which one is better

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, storyboard

Is **Multiple Storyboard** in single project is better than **single storyboard**??if yes then why??

Which is better **Single Storyboard** or **Multiple Storyboard**??

Any one please clear me the above queries.

Comment: it depends on your application screen's if number of screen are more then single storyboard might look little crowded and other devs working on same project will get diffuculties getting proper controller. on other case if you create different sotryboards then it will be more clear and easy to make changes in it and easy to understand for others

Answer (score 3):

**It depends on the project requirement.** If you are good enough with the `size classes` and `auto-layout` and also if the requirement flow is almost similar for all the devices then go with  ***single storyboard***.

By default in Xcode 6 or later, recommending to use single storyBoard.

Comment: Kumar KL: Have you ever worked on a storyboard with 2 people at the same time on GIT and tried it to merge ? IF not, I would recommend to you, to try that. In that case your answer will change

Answer (score 3):

If you have a bigger app and/or not only one man team:

You should NOT use single story board. Like its name says, it is a "STORY" board. You should have one Story in one Board. This keeps the readability and maintainability of the storyboard.

If you have a team, it is a nightmare to "merge" one single story board if 2 made changes in it at the same time. It is more or less impossible. But if you have for each story a corresponding storyboard, even in a scrum team you can manage to work on one storyboard only one person, that you do not need merging.

There are a lot usefull documents and workshops in internet if you google "ios storyboard git merge ...."

Answer (score 2):

### When to Use Storyboards

Finally, while Storyboards are best used for scenarios involving multiple view controllers, it’s also defensible to use a Storyboard when working with a single table view controller for three reasons:

- **The ability to design table cell prototypes in-place helps keep the pieces together.**
- **Multiple cell templates can be designed inside the parent table view controller.**
- **It’s possible to create static table views (a long awaited addition that’s unfortunately only available in Storyboards).**

### When Not to Use iOS Storyboards

A few cases:

- **The view has a complicated or dynamic layout, best-implemented with code.**
- **The view is already implemented with NIBs or code.**

### When to Use NIBs for iOS UI Design

A subset of all uses cases would be:

- **Modal views**
- **Simple login and registration views**
- **Settings**
- **Popup windows**
- **Reusable view templates**
- **Reusable table cell templates**
  Meanwhile…

### When Not to Use NIBs

You should avoid using NIBs for:

- **Views with dynamic content, where the layout changes significantly depending on content.**
- **Views that by nature are not easily designable in the Interface Builder.**
- **View controllers with complicated transitions that could be simplified with Storyboarding.**

Answer (score 1):

Apple's docs say that you may have multiple storyboards. Unfortunately they don't go into any real detail on how to do that. As you've found out, Interface Builder won't help you, so you'll have to do it in code. It works much like loading XIBs:

```
[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@”MyNewStoryboard” bundle:myBundle]
```

Having said that, if you don't "want one big/bloated storyboard" as then XIBs really are the way to go. That 'bigness' is the benefit: all the transitions between VCs are laid out in one place. Having multiple storyboards is really so that you can support multiple different and unrelated flows through your app: for example, one storyboard for a complex configuration flow and another one for the main user flow.